# Can I use a URL as the database directory for the reader function in geoip2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, geolocation, geoip, maxmind

I'm running

```
import geoip2.database
reader = geoip2.database.Reader("https://url.com/.../GeoLite2-City.mmdb")
```

And it returns

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'https://url.com/.../GeoLite2-City.mmdb'
```

Is there some way for me to reference a URL as the destination for this function?

EDIT:

```
import geoip2.database
import urllib2
r = urllib2.urlopen("https://url.com/.../GeoLite2-City.mmdb")
temp = r.read()
reader = geoip2.database.Reader(temp)
```

returns

```
TypeError: file() argument 1 must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str
```

Comment: it can't resolve the path just from a URL. You need to GET the file. For example, using `urllib2` do `r = urllib2.urlopen("https://url.com/.../GeoLite2-City.mmdb")` then write `r.read()` into a file or temp file object. If you don't want to download the file locally, then use their API (pay for it).

Comment: Updated with the results

Comment: You need to create a file object and *write* the contents of `r.read()` into the file then pass the file handle to Reader(). As I previously stated: " then **write** `r.read()` into a file or temp file object." Reader expects a string with a file path. It handles opening and reading the file

Comment: **write** into a file. Take a Python tutorial if you don't know how to do this. You can't just assign it to a variable. That's not a file nor a file object. It's a variable. Files must be opened then written to.

Comment: Working on it now

Comment: E.g. `with open('temp.db', 'wb') as f: f.write(r.read())`. Then you pass 'temp.db' to Reader()

Comment: Sure, the issue is that I'm working in a virtual environment so I'm trying to figure out the permissions

Comment: Issue seems to be resolved. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. From there you can just delete the temp file or set up some rules to delete it after so long. I recommend using the API, it's pretty cheap and faster than downloading the database.